# Shape mismatch when attempting to calculate position of unknown coordinate in cartesian system

Tags: python, math

**The Problem**

Hi guys, I am trying to make a system where I can map markers on my ceiling using OpenCV. For this to work I need to be able to calculate the position of a new marker, using the known positions of old ones. When I run the script below I get the following error:

> TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output
> shape of the 'func' argument 'unknown_point_equations'.Shape should be
> (2,) but it is (3,).

**Expected Results**

The expected results are of course the correct coordinates for the (x,y) and not an error.

**The Code**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def unknown_point_equations(variables, x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3):
    x, y = variables
    eq1 = (x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 - d1**2
    eq2 = (x - x2)**2 + (y - y2)**2 - d2**2
    eq3 = (x - x3)**2 + (y - y3)**2 - d3**2
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]

def calculate_unknown_point(x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3):
    # Initial guess for the unknown point
    initial_guess = [0, 0]

    # Solve the system of equations
    result, infodict, ier, msg = fsolve(unknown_point_equations, initial_guess, args=(x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3), full_output=True)

    if ier != 1:
        raise RuntimeError(f"fsolve did not converge: {msg}")

    # Extract the coordinates of the unknown point
    x_p, y_p = result[0], result[1]

    return x_p, y_p
```

**Values for replication**

```
x1, y1, d1 = 324,300,147

x2, y2, d2 = 278,414,224

x3, y2, d3, = 357,437,276
```

Comment: You have three equations, [eq1, eq2, eq3] in two unknowns [x,y]. In general, we would not expect any solutions to this, an over determined system, which is why fsolve does not work. Try using just 2 of the equations and then check if your solution satisfies the third.

Comment: As you are finding the intersection of two circles. There is an explicit formula see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch between your input and output. Your input is

```py
initial_guess = [0, 0]
```

And your output is, per the function signature of `unknown_point_equations`:

```py
[eq1, eq2, eq3]
```

You can fix this by just having a dummy variable. `fsolve` is unhappy if your function does not go for N length vector to an N length vector (essentially, your function must be a linear map).

My gut instinct is that your initial guess should be `[0, 0, 0]`, and you should do nothing with the third variable. Happy hunting!

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def unknown_point_equations(variables, x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3):
    x, y, _ = variables
    eq1 = (x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 - d1**2
    eq2 = (x - x2)**2 + (y - y2)**2 - d2**2
    eq3 = (x - x3)**2 + (y - y3)**2 - d3**2
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]

def calculate_unknown_point(x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3):
    # Initial guess for the unknown point
    initial_guess = [0, 0, 0]

    # Solve the system of equations
    result, infodict, ier, msg = fsolve(
      unknown_point_equations,
      initial_guess,
      args=(x1, y1, d1, x2, y2, d2, x3, y3, d3),
      full_output=True
    )

    if ier != 1:
        raise RuntimeError(f"fsolve did not converge: {msg}")

    # Extract the coordinates of the unknown point
    x_p, y_p, _ = result

    return x_p, y_p
```

(Although, for what its worth, that doesn't converge for the values you've provided. You'll need a different starting point.)